# How to deploy a Firefox extension in XULRunner/GeckoFX?

Tags: xulrunner, geckofx

I have a developed a binary extension that works fine under Firefox, but cannot manage to deploy it in XULRunner/GeckoFX. The extension doesn't have a UI and just provides an API to our main application (in .NET).

All tutorials I could find explain how to install them into a XULRunner *application*. But by using GeckoFX, XULRunner is running embedded in my project, so I don't have a XULRunner application.

I've already tried copying the installed extension's directory from Firefox's profile directory to XULRunner's profile, and also to use the FF profile directory for GeckoFX, both to no avail.

My current suspicion is that the extension's `targetApplication` in `install.rdf` needs to be adjusted for GeckoFX, but what's the correct id?

Since we are deploying GeckoFX/XULRunner embedded in our project, I don't need the extension manager, a static deployment would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to get it to work. Here's what I did:

First, add the location where the extension is deployed using `Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister()`:

```
void RegisterExtensionDir(string dir)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Registering binary extension directory:  " + dir);
    var chromeDir = (nsIFile)Xpcom.NewNativeLocalFile(dir);
    var chromeFile = chromeDir.Clone();
    chromeFile.Append(new nsAString("chrome.manifest"));
    Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister(chromeFile);
}
```

Second, do **not** use the ABI flag in the extension's `chrome.manifest`. So instead of

```
binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll  ABI=WINNT_x86-msvc
```

I used

```
binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll
```

I consider this a bug of GeckoFX 29 and have created an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issue/216/binary-extensions-fail-to-load-when-abi) for that.

Comment: Is `dir` a path to a .xpi file? I'm looking for a way to install add-ons to `GeckoFX`, but can't find a way.

Comment: Another copy paste answer from bitbuchet which is not working. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Anybody find a solution to this yet?